# Download Large file in nodejs

Tags: python, node.js

I am building an application where I call a python process using child-process module which creates an Excel file and downloads it using req.download method.The process runs well in my local machine but when I move it to the Server,many times the connection gets timed out while downloading the file.Please help me to solve this problem.Here is the code of the process

```js
app.get('/RawReport',function(req,res){
     
     
     console.log('Property........................'+req.param('property'))
        var result=''
         
        var month_picker=req.param('monthSelected')
      
          var py1 =spawn('python',[process.cwd()+'/routes/Reporting/Raw_Story_Report_03.py',req.param('property'),month_picker,global_user.name]);

          py1.stdout.on('data',function(data){
              result=data.toString()
             // res.download(result)
          });

          py1.stderr.on('data',function(data){
              console.log('err====',data.toString())
          });
          py1.on('close',function(code){
              var result_path=result.split('\n')[0]
              res.download(result_path)
            })
    })
```

Comment: i mean it downloads the files completely sometimes right

Comment: i think you should put end instead of close on this very code py1.on('close',function(code)